# How to apply custom data formatting/map to each event before loading the entire dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

The standard way from the [documentation](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/02/23/working-complex-data-formats-structured-streaming-apache-spark-2-1.html) to read a stream of data into Apache Spark is:

```py
events = spark.readStream \
  .format("json") \           # or parquet, kafka, orc...
  .option() \                 # format specific options
  .schema(my_schema) \        # required
  .load("path/to/data")
```

But I need to clean up some of the data re-arrange some of the fields before I apply the schema, I was hoping there would be a

```py
events = spark.readStream \
  .format("json") \           # or parquet, kafka, orc...
  .option() \                 # format specific options
  .schema(my_schema) \        # required
  **.map(custom_function)**   # apply a custom function to the json object
  .load("path/to/data")
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in Apache Spark using Structured Streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Short answer, you can't do this before loading your dataset.

The only way that comes to my mind is to load your dataset as a set of strings and clean them up with a series of `withColumn` or `select` transformations, effectively being your `.map(custom_function)`.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Jacek's answer. More specifically, you have two options:

1. Apply a "super-schema" of the input data and then manipulate to the schema you want. That is the best approach when (a) all your data is valid JSON and (b) the "super-schema" is somewhat stable, e.g., dynamic field names are not present.
2. Read as text, parse using `json4s` (or another library of your choosing), manipulate as needed. This is the best approach if (a) any input rows may not be valid JSON or (b) there is no stable "super-schema".